# Facebook Policies: Can my application automatically post stories to my Facebook stream?

Tags: facebook, policy, facebook-wall

According to the [Facebook Platform Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> You must not pre-fill the user_message
>   parameter or content sent via an
>   extended permission (such as a status
>   update or note), unless the user
>   generated the content earlier in the
>   workflow.

Does that mean that I can't publish stories to the stream automatically, even if the user agreed to?

I've seen apps (such as PlayStation Network, Foto Diaria) that publish stories automatically.

PlayStation Network publishes stories about actions you did in PS3 games and Foto Diaria publishes a picture from your wall every day. In both cases the attachment is created by the application, and the user message is empty. Could that mean that publishing stories with an empty user message (empty, not absent) is not considered pre-filling?

EDIT: I need to know what is allowed or not by the Facebook Platform Policies, not how to post stories.

Answer (score 2):

If you ask the user for the [`publish_stream` extended permission](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions/Stream_permissions) then you'll be able to post automatically whilst the user is interacting with the application. You can pre-fill the user message only if it's something that the user has entered earlier in the process e.g. if you've asked them to comment on a piece of content and then publish a story about the comment. If in doubt, leave it blank.

If you want to publish automatically even when the user isn't online then you'll also need them to grant the application the [`offline_access` extended permission](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions). In this case you'll also need to store the session key that Facebook gives you for that user.

Comment: Kari B, thanks for your answer. I already know how extended permissions and pu blishing stream stories work. My question is about what is allowed according to the policies.

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/stream_stories/

Check this out. The Platform policies section of the FB Dev site has some additional documents to allow you gain a better understanding of the guidelines for sharing.

Please also read the section about User Feedback.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/user_feedback/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We can ask user to grain of offline_access permission, which is access to user profile at anytime, even if user is not online. But this permission will no longer available.

I agree that this permission is so harmful to user.

But it still useful if owner app want to post to their own account during user use their app. If you want to post to your self account, you can manually grain offline_access to your app, and select access_token and keep it in your own app, and use it when you need to post your account. It make sense that Facebook should allow developer to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

it is simply forbidden but, there is a catch about it, if is text prepared by user previously, you can post that text later and I think you are able to add your own text to that. But not so sure..

I'm saying this based on [McDonald's Canada's yourquestions](http://yourquestions.mcdonalds.ca/) app, you can ask questions to them, whenever its answered they posting to your wall.

But to clarify that, as a PMD I'll ask to FB personally and let you know what is the answer is.