# Is automatic posting by POST /{user-id}/feed API is allowed by policy?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does Facebook Platform Policy allows to post messages and/or share links automatically?

My question is exactly same as a post below. However, I'm wondering if answers to the post are still effective because it seems that Platform Policy has been revised since then, and now we need to pass login review to be granted publishing permissions.

[Facebook Policies: Can my application automatically post stories to my Facebook stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074993/facebook-policies-can-my-application-automatically-post-stories-to-my-facebook)

Comment: We are not lawyers. It wouldn't be a good idea to ask for advice regarding the interpretation of Facebook's policies.

Comment: In addition: "`My question is exactly same as a post below.`" - please don't duplicate content in this manner.

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook's API policy and not a programming question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autoposting is not allowed, was not allowed and will most likely never be. It would basically be spam.

> Policy 2.1: Obtain consent from people before publishing content on
>   their behalf.

That means **for every single post**, of course.

Comment: Autoposting and obtaining consent are different matter. One can explain users what will be autoposted, ask consent, and enable autoposting if a user say yes.

Comment: no. every single post has to get authorized. this has been discussed a lot of times in the facebook developers group already, but it´s pretty clear anyway as it would be spammy - even if the user accepted autoposting.

Comment: However, I am concerned about this sentence; `Don’t confuse, deceive, defraud, mislead, spam or surprise anyone.` Does autoposting surprise users? Are there anyone who implemented autoposting and passed login review or got rejected?

Comment: it is not allowed, so you don´t pass the login review for sure. and it´s definitely surprising for the friends of the user if stuff gets autoposted - for example, while he is not even online.